# Python subprocess assign value to a variable

Tags: python

I am using the following code:

```
import subprocess
#subprocess.call(["cat","contents.txt"])
command = "VAR=$(cat contents.txt | grep token)"
subprocess.call(command, shell = True)
subprocess.call(["echo","$VAR"])
```

I am trying to assign value of token present in contents.txt to a variable and i am trying to print the variable. But i am not getting anything. What corrections can be done here.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your file exists and it is in PATH or local folder?

Comment: You can more easily access environment variables with `os.environ`

Comment: Have you looked into subprocess.check_output? https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: @SlLoWre yes i am sure file is in same path. Because above command is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got to do everything in one process, since `os.environ` is for the particular python process and `subprocess` executes your commands in another process, you can't access it from there.

you also can't do it in two different `subprocess.call` calls since each is another process and you could not access the variable from the second one, therefore you have to execute everything in the same process, all commands at the same line, separated by ";", as follows:

```py
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run('VAR=$(cat contents.txt | grep token); echo $VAR', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print(result.stdout.decode())
```

in my `contents.txt` file I have "token=123", and hence the result of `result.stdout.decode()` was "token=123" as well :D